# Peterson Algorithm as a binary tree

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, concurrency, binary-tree

I am currently trying to write a Java program that solves this.

"Another way to generalize the two-thread Peterson lock is to arrange a number of 2-thread Peterson locks in a binary tree. Suppose n is a power of two. Each thread is assigned a leaf lock which it shares with one other thread. Each lock treats one thread as thread 0 and the other as thread 1."

I feel like I have solved it, but my output is not always correct. I suspect my problem is in the for loop in my lock method that calls a verified Peterson lock (Peterson lock has no errors in that it was provided to solve this problem). I basically build a balanced binary tree, declare an array of Peterson Algorithm instances, and, as each thread comes in, I have use the tree as an index and call the Peterson locks.

```
package mutex;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;

public class tree_lock implements Lock{

int total_instances;
int thread_instances = 0;
int N;
static int cnt = 0;
static int cnt2 = 0;
int flag = 0;
Node root;
Peterson[] PeterInstances;
int[] IncomingThreadIDs;

final private ThreadLocal<Integer> THREAD_ID2 = new ThreadLocal<Integer>(){
    final private AtomicInteger id2 = new AtomicInteger(0);

    protected Integer initialValue(){
        return id2.getAndIncrement();
    }
};


//Constructor   : tree_lock Constructor
//Input         : n, the number of threads
//Descritpion   : Determine number of instances fore each thread, Create IDs for each thread, 
//                Create Balanced Binary Tree of with keys numbered from 0 to n
tree_lock(int n)
{
    N=n;
    int temp = n;
    total_instances = n - 1;
    int[] IDs = new int[total_instances];

    //Determine number of instances of each thread
    while(temp != 1)
    {
        temp /=2;
        thread_instances++;
    }

    PeterInstances = new Peterson[total_instances];
    for(int i = 0; i < total_instances; i++)
    {
        PeterInstances[i] = new Peterson();
    }
    IncomingThreadIDs = new int[n];

    //Create IDs for each thread
    for(int i = 0; i < n;i+=2)
    {
        IncomingThreadIDs[i] = cnt;
        IncomingThreadIDs[i+1] = cnt;

        cnt+=2;
    }
    //Create array with keys for each node in binary tree
    for(int i = 0; i < total_instances;i++)
    {
        IDs[i]=i;
    }
    //Create binary tree with keys from above array
    BuildTree(0,IDs.length-1,IDs);
}

//Function   : BuildTree
//Input      : lowest index of array, high index of array, pointer to array
//Output     : Balanced Binary Tree
//Description: Createds a Balanced Binary Tree
//Credit to: http://linwdav.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-build-balanced-binary-search.html
public Node BuildTree(int low, int high, int[] arr)
{       
    if(low > high)
        return null;
    else
    {
        int mid = (low + high)/2;
        Node node = new Node(arr[mid]);
        if(flag == 0)
        {
            root = node;
            flag++;
        }
        node.leftChild = BuildTree(low,(mid-1),arr);
        node.rightChild = BuildTree((mid+1),high,arr);
        return node;
    }

}

//Function    : findNodeParent
//Input       : key for a node
//Output      : key of parent node
//Description : Determines the key for a parent node
public int findNodeParent(int key)
{
    if(root.key == key)
        return  -1;
    Node focusNode = root;

    while(focusNode.leftChild.key != key && focusNode.rightChild.key != key)
    {
        if(key < focusNode.key)
        {
            focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;
        }
        else
        {
            focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;
        }
    }

    return focusNode.key;
}

//Function    : lock
//Description : locks other threads
public void lock()
{
    //get thread ID
    int cnt3 = (THREAD_ID2.get() % N);

    int[] path = new int[thread_instances];
    path[0] = IncomingThreadIDs[cnt3];

    //create path to root node
    for(int k = 1; k < thread_instances; k++)
    {
        path[k] = findNodeParent(path[k-1]);
    }
    //attempt to lock thread up to root node
    for(int i = 0; i < thread_instances; i++)
    {
            //********************************
            //Problem is here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        PeterInstances[path[i]].lock();
            //ThreadID = findNodeParent(ThreadID);
    }

}
//Function   : unlock
//Description : unlocks other threads
public void unlock()
{
    //get thread ID
    int cnt3 = (THREAD_ID2.get() % N);

    //create path to root node
    int[] path = new int[thread_instances];
    path[0] = IncomingThreadIDs[cnt3];

    for(int k = 1; k < thread_instances; k++)
    {
        path[k] = findNodeParent(path[k-1]);
    }

    //attempt to unlock thread to the node
    for(int i = thread_instances - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        PeterInstances[path[i]].unlock();
    }
}

 // Any class implementing Lock must provide these methods
public Condition newCondition() {
throw new java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException();
}
public boolean tryLock(long time,
           TimeUnit unit)
throws InterruptedException {
throw new java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException();
}
public boolean tryLock() {
throw new java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException();
}
public void lockInterruptibly() throws InterruptedException {
throw new java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException();
}

}

class Node
{
int key;

Node leftChild;
Node rightChild;
Node parent;

Node(int key)
{
    this.key = key;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have pointed out the problem precisely. You have to make this code synchronized. I guess the superclass lock() you are calling is not synchronized.

Just doing this will solve the problem.

```
synchronized (this){
            PeterInstances[path[i]].lock();
        }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The Peterson locks I was using was giving the same ID to different threads. I had to alter the Peterson lock code to accommodate mine. Since the Peterson lock was given, I never gave it a look. Thanks for replying!